# The annotation PersistenceContext will not be recognized by WebSphere Application Server v7.0 runtimes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, websphere

I am getting the error message in Websphere when trying to use JPA @PersistenceContext annotation.

I am using JPA 2.0 and hibernate as persistence provider, have all the required hibernate 3.5 jar files in classpath.

Why does this error message appear?

Problem description: The annotation 
 PersistenceContext will not be recognized by 
 WebSphere Application Server v7.0 runtimes. Set the 
 UseEJB61FEPScanPolicy custom property to true in 
 the MANIFEST.MF file for this module.

Comment: Have you set the <provider> tag and modified Classloader policy as descirbed [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftejb_jpa3rdparty.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like WebSphere perceives your application as J2EE, not Java EE 5. Check the deployment descriptor of your EAR (`application.xml`) and that of EJB jars, if they conform to Java EE 5.

EDIT: Your Hibernate version may also be the cause, if your WAS is not extended with the "OSGI and JPA 2 feature pack". Hibernate 3.5 implements JPA 2.0, Hibernate 3.3 — JPA 1.0 (see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183654/websphere-7-and-application-based-open-jpa-2/7381955#7381955)).