# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, websphere, openjpa, ibm-rad

I am getting an error when I create a j2ee application in rad with IBM's Websphere server

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:113)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:202)
```

EDIT: 
The auto generated persistence.xml is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PLHService">
        <class>plh.jpa.entity.User</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I tried adding the connection parameters to persistence.xml. It does not make a difference

I checked out an article at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?89055-jpa-2-0-persistence-xml-does-not-validate but i did not use hibernate

The build path is the default set in rad and websphere 7.0.

Comment: You need to post the file in question. Your `persistence.xml` maybe? The `SAXParseException` stacktrace is useless; the message is the only part helping us.

Comment: Does Websphere have a local XML catalog that provides the resolution for the `xsi:schemalocation`? If so it may be overriding the external link to the XSD and providing the wrong one (v 1.0) which would result in the error you're seeing.

Comment: So you use what JPA implementation and what version ? OpenJPA ? and a version that only supports JPA1?

Comment: @DataNucleus well, i could not find a way out... so i'm currently using 1.0... planning to upgrade later to was8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The build path is the default set in rad and websphere 7.0.

By default Websphere 7.0 uses a wrapped version of OpenJPA 1.0. If you want to fix this either use 1.0 in your persistence.xml file, or [switch the persistence provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183654/websphere-7-and-application-based-open-jpa-2) in RAD and WAS, or you could alternatively [apply the JPA2.0 feature pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/featurepacks/osgi/features/?S_CMP=wspace).

Answer (score 2):

Does WebSphere 7.0 support JPA 2.0.

The answer is **no!!**.  As suggested by Terrell you should explore using the JPA 2.0 Feature pack in which case, you should be able to use JPA 2.0.

You should also look at this post

[websphere 7 and (application based) open-jpa 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183654/websphere-7-and-application-based-open-jpa-2)

I would also suggest you look at wsjpaversion to see the support for JPA in your set up.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Frejb_wsjpaversion.html&resultof=%22newfeat%22%20

Hope these provide you with good pointers.