# Why does the deployment of a Spring Boot application to a WebSphere 7 app server cause a ClassCastException?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, websphere-7

I am having Spring Boot application using JPA with Hibernate and tried to deploy on WebSphere application server 7.0.0.33.

I included the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 117 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1292)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:746)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:287)
    ... 130 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl incompatible with javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1307)
    ... 142 common frames omitted
```

Is anybody having idea on this ?

Comment: WebSphere uses its own JPA API. You may try to mark hibernate-jpa-2.0-api as provided

Comment: Thanks for quick response classCast exception solved but now getting Error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.persistence.spi.ProviderUtil".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things here:

1. You don't need to declare Hibernate dependencies individually. The declaration of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` will include everything you need. So remove all of the manually declared dependencies and verify the setup by executing `mvn dependency:list`. This should show you a JPA *2.1* API JAR on the classpath as Hibernate 4.2.x versions require JPA 2.1. Also, bootstrap your Boot application standalone to verify it's working (writing an integration test using a Spring Data JPA repository would effectively achieve the same thing).
2. Deploying to WebSphere 7 will require you to configure the `ClassLoader` hierarchy to be parent-last so that classpath lookups will inspect application JARs first instead of the ones provided by the container. If parent-first is enabled (and that's the default correctly) the JPA JARs that WebSphere ships will be found first (1.0 for a standard 7, 2.0 for a 7 with the JPA feature pack) and none of them will work with a recent Hibernate (as it requires JPA 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere 7.0 has JPA 1.0 built in and it will not run JPA 2.0. For JPA 2.0 you will need JPA feature pack installed. Check this post for more details - [websphere 7 and (application based) open-jpa 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183654/websphere-7-and-application-based-open-jpa-2)

Comment: I have installed Websphere 7 using launchpad not using installation manager, How would i apply Feature Pack for OSGi Applications and JPA 2.0 ?.